# Ruby: Return Value from Key Value Pair

Tags: ruby

So I'm brand new to Ruby and I'm completely stuck. I'm rendering links with Objects that have a property of `url`. But, I want to test a theory out so instead of just rendering the URL as is I want create a different URL. What I want to do is to look at the Argument Object's ID and if it matches a key in a specified object then I want to change how the URL is constructed.

```
def perform_redirect(myObj)
  redirects = { 111 => 222, 333 => 444, 555 => 666 }

  if (redirects.has_key? myObj[:id])
    # I'm stuck here, ideal return is:
    return "https://myurl.com/#{redirects.assoc myObj[:id][1]}"
  else
    return myObj[:url]
  end
end
```

I'm reading a bunch of stuff on Ruby arrays and it doesn't make a whole lot of sense or maybe there is a completely different way I should be approaching this problem.

**Expected result**

*Change the URL*

- If `myObj = {id: 111, url: "https://somesite.com/111"}`
- `myObj.id` matches a `key` in `redirects`
- Return new URL of `https://myurl.com/222`

*Don't change URL*

- If `myObj = {id: 12345, url: "https://somesite.com/12345"}`
- `myObj.id` does not match a `key` in `redirects`
- Return `myObj.url` which is `https://somesite.com/12345`

Comment: What would be the value of `myObj[:id][1]`? can you add some input and expected result?

Comment: I've add expected results to the question hopefully that makes it a little more clear.

Comment: am i missing something crucial here or is it just `https://myurl.com/#{redirects[myObj[:id]]}` what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope, that was the answer. Thank you, idk why this just isn't registering with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wiesion mentioned in the comments the data wanted wasn't be called correctly is all

`return "https://myurl.com/#{redirects.assoc myObj[:id][1]}"`

Needs to be

`https://myurl.com/#{redirects[myObj[:id]]}`